# How can I make a certain section of an image clickable?

Tags: html, css

I'm new at coding, and I have a problem where I need to have my toheader or rather, my top navbar, to let someone click the contents within it. It makes sense to use html text, but I ran into problems with dreamweaver not letting me put text above my background image, which you'll see is right below my top navbar. So, instead, I made the top navbar an image, and I need the "facebook" icon on the navbar to be clickable. Someone said use an area tag, but it seems all too confusing for someone as young to coding as I am.

Jsfiddle [contains css]
http://jsfiddle.net/6LA75/

```
<body>
<img src="images/page composition/NavBar.png" />

<div id="wrapperstalled"
   <div id="logo">
   <img src="images/logo/logo-vector.png" />
   </div>
</div>


<div id="wrapper">
   <STYLE TYPE="text/css">
   <!--
   P {text-indent: 8pt;}
   -->
   </STYLE>

   <div id="aboutus">   
       <p>We are a Hagerstown-based junk removal and moving service. Able to accomplish jobs both big and small, we accept residential, commerical, and industrial jobs. </p>
       <p>&nbsp;</p>
       <p>Active since 2014, we are a relatively new service looking to help as many people as possible. Visit our Facebook Page to stay posted on our recent works, job openings,        special offers and more. </p>
   </div>

   <div id="scheduling">
     <p>To schedule for a service, please provide the information listed
     below and we will respond promptly.</p>
   </div>

   <div id="contactus">
   <p>If you have any questions, comments, or concerns, our contact information is listed below.</p>
   <p>&nbsp;</p>
   <p>Phone: (443) 690 6421</p>
   <p>Email: service@hagdustboy.com</p>
   </div>   
</div>

</body>
```

---

Here is what my browser view of the webpage looks like. 
http://www.pixentral.com/show.php?picture=1UA4sXXTUMVf6eLFnJS2E4c75rzKy1

I want to make the circled area clickable.

Comment: Use the area and map tags: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_area.asp

Comment: "dreamweaver" well there is your problem right there.

Comment: Please read the first sentance of the tour : http://stackoverflow.com/tour then perhaps rephrase your question.

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob please find a better reference than W3Schools (http://w3fools.com/) perhaps: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map

Comment: Alarm bell one, using an image for the nav bar! Use text styles and images. Alarm bell two, spaces in directory names. This should be avoided, and if not makesure you escape the space properly (%20) in any href or similar attributes.

Comment: @Jon P, the example found there is perfectly fine, though I agree lots of times the site is subpar....did you look at the example at the link I provided?

Answer (score 0):

Change the **coords** and **href** and **src** attributes according to your need.

```
<div id="logo">
   <img src="http://www.brookhavencollege.edu/images/bhc/icons/facebook.png" usemap="#logolink" />
 <map name="logolink">
   <area shape="rect" coords="200,10,30,30" href="#">
   <area shape="rect" coords="250,10,300,50" href="#">
 </map>
</div>
```

Comment: hello ahj. thank yo for your help. It's working fine except for one component. When I click the area, a blue outline surrounds the area. It's not a huge deal but it looks a bit out of place. Is there any remedy for that? Thanks.

Comment: just add a css rule to your stylesheet for ***anchor tags border to be none*** `a{border:none}`. Hope that will fix the problem. :) These problems are probable to occur on internet explorer or older browsers. Tweaking the css will do the trick.